# How to pass an actual object (i.e. reference to an object) to a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, json

In my Angular app, I have a few nested ng-repeats to parse through some expected JSON objects, for example:

```
     {
         landAnimals: {
              horse: {
                   sound: "Nay",
                   legs: 4,
              },
              beaver: {
                    sound: "thwack",
                    legs: 2
              }
         },
         waterAnimals: {
              dolphin: {
                   sound: "Eee",
                   fins: 3,
              },
              goldfish: {
                    sound: "-",
                    fins: 1
              }
         }

    }
```

At one point, what I would like to do is pass the animal category to my directive and another animal object to it.

For example, if a user drags another animal into the list that is generated in my app, I want to add the animal he dragged into the JSON above.

To do this, I'm trying to pass the animal object to a directive and then adding the new animal to it.

For instance:

```
<div ng-repeat="animalCategory in animals on-drop-success='animalCategory'">
     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in animalCategory">
         {{key}}
     </div>
</div>
```

and then in my `onDropSuccess` directive, in the `link` function, I am trying 
(don't worry about how I'm doing the drag and drop, it's not working even with this simple test)

```
...
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
     attrs.onDropSuccess["newAnimal"] = {sound: "miy", legs: 2};
...
```

**To summarize, I am trying to pass the `animalCategory` object to my directive so I can add more objects under it. But it's not working. It doesn't add the object even when I manually provide a naive object (i.e. it has nothing to do with the drag implementation)**

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is your directive's `link` function getting executed at all? If not, fix your template to really use the directive as element attribute (not part of the expression in `ng-repeat`).

Comment: can you setup a fiddle we can play with?

Comment: @MattWay Here's something very similar. When a `Boy` or `Girl` is dragged, I want to add to the person object it was dragged over http://codepen.io/Raphi/pen/dPoYvX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you aren't referencing an actual object, only a property on the [`attrs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) construct that will return a string.

There are a couple of ways you could pull in an actual reference.

**Using [`scope.$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)**

```
//Target object will be pulled in if it exists on the scope
// this will not work if you are using Isolate Scope
var targetObject = scope.$eval(attrs.onDropSuccess);
```

**Using `=` parameters on [Isolate Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)**

You can pull in parameters into the directives isolate scope by using the [`scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) property on the directive definition.

```
{
  scope:{
     onDropSuccess: '='
  }
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
     //Basically same as above, except that they 
     // are pulled from the parent scope
     var targetObject = scope.onDropSuccess;
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly. Can you explain why it was giving me a String and why why `$eval` makes it an object?

Comment: @Imray - `attrs` is just a construct that gives you normalized access the attributes of the element. The result is either the string, or the interpolated result of an expression. e.g. {{1 + 2}} will be `3`, but the result is still a string. `$eval` will actually execute that expression against the scope, and return the result. In this case, it's the name of a property on the scope, so the result is the object/value stored in that property.

Comment: I discovered a problem with your answer and that is that `$eval` disconnects the object from it's parent. Meaning, if I now make changes to this object, it doesn't reflect in the original JSON object. For example, if I make a change to `landAnimals` after it's been put through `$eval`, I don't see the change in the `$scope.animals` variable in my controller

Comment: Well... if you are replacing the reference with another reference then that would make sense. They would actually point to two different objects.

Comment: so `$eval` creates a new copy of the object right? Is there any way to keep the reference from the object being iterated over in `ng-repeat`?